# C code works on my PC but on grader system doesn't

Tags: c

I have a problem with the code that I wrote. I have some test cases that have the results for the same. When I run these TC on my laptop the result is as expected, but when I upload code to my class grader only the first one doesn't work and says that the algorithm is not good or that there is some infinite loop. I think that the code is good; maybe I am wrong. What do you think?

Test Case 1:

```
[11:25] Bogadi Alen: Kameleon
[11:25] Begovic Amir: Magarac
[11:25] Novak Anel: Tapir
[11:25] Milanja Ante: Jelen
[11:25] Mavracic Antonio: Morski pas
[11:35] Dutkovic Ivan: Vuk
[11:35] Kulic Ivan: Orao
[11:53] Prekratic Ivan: Kameleon
[11:53] Vuletic Jaksa: Krava
[11:53] Bakaric Jan: Kameleon
[11:53] Mladar Jan: Majmun
[12:13] Bakran Josip: Slon
[12:13] Profesor Ivan: Kameleon
```

Expected result:

```
Broj studenata koji su pogodili zivotinju: 3 od 12.

Studenti koji su pogodili zivotinju:
Bogadi Alen
Prekratic Ivan
Bakaric Jan
```

Test Case 2:

```
[14:27] Profesor Ivan: Pas
```

Expected result:

```
Vise srece drugi put!
```

Here I put 2 TC and the first one is not working properly...

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    //x-igralo, y-pogodilo
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    //da li prvi put unosim podatke
    int prviput = 1;
    char profime[9] = "Profesor";
    int brojredova = 1;
    //alociranje memorije-pocetno
    char** ime = (char**)calloc(brojredova, sizeof(char*));
    char** prezime = (char**)calloc(brojredova, sizeof(char*));
    char** zivotinja = (char**)calloc(brojredova, sizeof(char*));
    char time[30];
    char tprez[30];
    char tzivotinja[30];

    do {
        //trenutno predstavlja index reda
        int indx = brojredova - 1;
        if (prviput)
        {
            scanf("%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c %[^ ] %[^:]%*c %[^\n]", time, tprez, tzivotinja);
            int len = strlen(tzivotinja);

            //alociram memoriju za duzinu imena,prezimena
            *(ime + indx) = (char*)calloc(strlen(time), sizeof(char));
            *(prezime + indx) = (char*)calloc(strlen(tprez), sizeof(char));
            *(zivotinja + indx) = (char*)calloc(strlen(tzivotinja), sizeof(char));

            strcpy(*(ime + indx), time);
            strcpy(*(prezime + indx), tprez);
            strcpy(*(zivotinja + indx), tzivotinja);

            //pretvaranje svih slova u mala zbog kasnije usporedbe
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            {
                if (isupper(*(*(zivotinja + indx) + j)))
                {
                    *(*(zivotinja + indx) + j) += 32;
                }
            }
            x++;
            prviput = 0;
            //ako je unesen korisnik koji nije profesor, alocira se jos 1 red za sljedeceg korisnika
            if (strcmp("Profesor", time) != 0)
            {
                brojredova++;

                ime = (char**)realloc(ime, brojredova * sizeof(char*));
                prezime = (char**)realloc(prezime, brojredova * sizeof(char*));
                zivotinja = (char**)realloc(zivotinja, brojredova * sizeof(char*));
            }

        }
        else
        {

            scanf("%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c %[^ ] %[^:]%*c %[^\n]", time, tprez, tzivotinja);
            int len = strlen(tzivotinja);
            //alociram memoriju za duzinu imena,prezimena
            *(ime + indx) = (char*)calloc(strlen(time), sizeof(char));
            *(prezime + indx) = (char*)calloc(strlen(tprez), sizeof(char));
            *(zivotinja + indx) = (char*)calloc(strlen(tzivotinja), sizeof(char));

            strcpy(*(ime + indx), time);
            strcpy(*(prezime + indx), tprez);
            strcpy(*(zivotinja + indx), tzivotinja);

            //pretvaranje svih slova u mala zbog kasnije usporedbe
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            {
                if (isupper(*(*(zivotinja + indx) + j)))
                {
                    *(*(zivotinja + indx) + j) += 32;
                }
            }
            x++;
            //ako je unesen korisnik koji nije profesor, alocira se jos 1 red za sljedeceg korisnika
            if (strcmp("Profesor", time) != 0)
            {
                brojredova++;

                ime = (char**)realloc(ime, brojredova * sizeof(char*));
                prezime = (char**)realloc(prezime, brojredova * sizeof(char*));
                zivotinja = (char**)realloc(zivotinja, brojredova * sizeof(char*));
            }
        }

    } while (strcmp("Profesor", time) != 0);
    x--;

    for (int i = 0; i <= x - 1; i++)
    {
        if ((strcmp(*(zivotinja + i), *(zivotinja + brojredova - 1)) == 0) || (strstr(*(zivotinja + i), *(zivotinja + brojredova - 1)) != NULL))
        {
            y++;
        }
    }

    //x-odirali
    if (x != 0)
    {
        printf("Broj studenata koji su pogodili zivotinju: %d od %d.\n\n", y, x);
        if (y == 0)
        {
            printf("Vise srece drugi put!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Studenti koji su pogodili zivotinju:\n");

            for (int i = 0; i <= x - 1; i++)
            {
                if ((strcmp(*(zivotinja + i), *(zivotinja + brojredova - 1)) == 0) || (strstr(*(zivotinja + i), *(zivotinja + brojredova - 1)) != NULL))
                {
                    printf("%s %s\n", *(ime + i), *(prezime + i));
                }
            }           
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Vise srece drugi put!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if the words were meaningful. I dont know what `zivotinja` is.

Comment: You should explain what this code is supposed to do!

Comment: Side note: consider using index notation - its much easier to read than pointer math. Ex: `*(*(zivotinja + indx) + j)` vs `zivotinja[indx][j]`

Comment: Aside: if you are trying to filter out the time elements like `[11:25]` instead of the tortuous `scanf("%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c %[^ ] %[^:]%*c %[^\n]", ...)` may I suggest the easier to read `scanf("%*s %[^ ] %[^:]%*c %[^\n]", ...)`?

Comment: Smells like a memory issue to me, try running the program on your laptop using valgrind, and see if any warning come up.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/xW8c871Gf

Comment: I am sorry that I didnt explain what the code does. Bacialy ime stands for name, prezime for surname, and zivotinja for animal. Program gets name surname and animal that person said in chat. User inputs information until ime(name) is profesor. Then, it searches for all persons who guessed the animal professor imagined-typed in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least these problems:

**Parsing is dodgy**

Input is *line* orientated, but `"%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c %[^ ] %[^:]%*c %[^\n]"` readily can go pass the line.

The best way to read a *line* from `stdin` is `fgets()`, then parse.

Use width limits.  Consider using `" %n"` to detect successful end of parsing.

```
#define LINE_SZ 200
char buf[LINE_SZ];

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  char time[30];
  char tprez[30];
  char tzivotinja[30];
  int n = 0;
  // Sample data: "[11:25] Mavracic Antonio: Morski pas"
  sscanf(buf, "[ %29[^]]] %29[^:]: %29[^\n] %n", 
      time, tprez, tzivotinja, &n);
  if (n == 0 || buf[n]) {
    puts("failed to parse all or extra junk.");
  } else {
    printf("time:<%s> tprez:<%s> tzivotinja:<%s>\n", 
        time, tprez, tzivotinja);
  }
}
```

**`"[ %29[^]]] %29[^:]: %29[^\n] %n"` break down:**

- `"["` Parse a `'['.
- `" "` Parse optional whitespaces.
- `"%29[^]]"` Parse 1 - 29 non-']' characters, save, append `\0`.
- `"]"` Parse a `']'.
- `" "` Parse optional whitespaces.
- `"%29[^:]"` Parse 1 - 29 non-':' characters, save, append `\0`.
- `":"` Parse a `':'.
- `" "` Parse optional whitespaces.
- `"%29[^\n]"` Parse 1 - 29 non-'\n' characters, save, append `\0`.
- `" "` Parse optional whitespaces.
- `"%n"` Save scan offset.

**Wrong allocation size**

Need 1 more for a *string*.  Cast is not needed.

```
// *(ime + indx) = (char*)calloc(strlen(time), sizeof(char)); // Bad
*(ime + indx) = calloc(strlen(time) + 1, sizeof(char));
...
strcpy(*(ime + indx), time);
```

**Avoid magic number**

Why 32?  Why not `'a' - 'A'`?  Or better, use `tolower()`

```
        //if (isupper(*(*(zivotinja + indx) + j))) {
        //  *(*(zivotinja + indx) + j) += 32;
        //}

        *(*(zivotinja + indx) + j) = tolower(*(*(zivotinja + indx) + j));
```